# Async for loop nodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a simple for loop containing an async function, my problem is that the loop goes through all the values, then only executes the async function inside.

```
for(key in splitedDataArray){
    calculatePower(splitedDataArray[key]);
    var octopusMAC = getOctopusIDFromRaw(splitedDataArray[key]);
    var channelID = getChannelIDFromRaw(splitedDataArray[key]);
    console.log("outside")
    getChannelCTSize(octopusMAC, channelID, function (result) {
        console.log("inside")
        var timestamp = convertDateTimeToInt(transmission.date);
        var adcTicks = getAdcTicksFromRaw(splitedDataArray[key]);
        var power = convertAdcTicksToAmps(parseInt(adcTicks, 16), result);
        console.log("channelID: " + channelID + " ADC ticks HEX: " + adcTicks + " timestamp: " + timestamp + " power for " + result + "A CT Size: " + power);
    });
}
```

So it prints outside for every element in the array then it only prints inside after all of the outised's, I want to have an outside then and inside and so on. I have looked at https://www.promisejs.org/ but I am not sure on how to implement this with my code.

Comment: So you want your calls to run in series? The easiest way, without using any external libraries, is to create a recursive function.

Comment: Check `async.each` http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each OR http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lodash.eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) but it is not best solution. If i were you i would try to move everything inside of for loop into a function so you will have all variables visible inside.
More like this:

```
function calculate(value){
    calculatePower(value);
    var octopusMAC = getOctopusIDFromRaw(value);
    var channelID = getChannelIDFromRaw(value);
    console.log("outside")
    getChannelCTSize(octopusMAC, channelID, function (result) {
        console.log("inside")
        var timestamp = convertDateTimeToInt(transmission.date);
        var adcTicks = getAdcTicksFromRaw(value);
        var power = convertAdcTicksToAmps(parseInt(adcTicks, 16), result);
        console.log("channelID: " + channelID + " ADC ticks HEX: " + adcTicks + " timestamp: " + timestamp + " power for " + result + "A CT Size: " + power);
    });
}

for(key in splitedDataArray){
    calc(splitedDataArray[key]);
}
```

It will not print out: out/in/out/in, but will get good values in each loop.
If you require that order /out/in/out/in i would go for eachSeries from lodash.